# How to save users progress on my website game?

Tags: javascript, html, save

I have developed a remake of cookie clicker with javascript and html. I put it up on my website and it works perfectly. The next step for me would be to try to save peoples progress so that it doesn't restart them every time they refresh the page. Is this possible? If it is (which I assume it is), how complicated is it as I am kind of new to coding? If you want to see the site, you can go here:

http://d3c.bea.myftpupload.com/pages/cookie_clicker.html

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can store page state data in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). Not really complicated especially if only saving a couple of items. Suggest you make a really simple test page to play with it a bit then integrate into your game once familiar with it

Comment: Alright I'll look into it! I will only need to store 4 variables, so I should be alright. Thanks a lot for the help!